# I updated Nightwatch to @latest and it breaks all of my tests. How can I upgrade the module without it breaking everything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nightwatch.js

[image]I updated to the latest version of nightwatch from npm. I get a strange error in the console (see attachments) and this is the first time it's happened. When I downgrade to nightwatch@0.9.21 all my tests work just fine. I need to know how I can upgrade to the latest version without my tests breaking. I have a separate project that is working on the latest version that has a similar file structure and that is compatible with Jenkins. My end game is to get these tests upgraded to the latest version of nightwatch to be able to put them in Jenkins.

I've tried other versions in the 1.x.x and I get different errors for each of them. I've tried taking out the code that it specifies in the console and it still gives me that same error.

```
{
"src_folders" : ["tests"],
"output_folder" : "reports/XMLReports",
"custom_commands_path" : "",
"custom_assertions_path" : "",
"page_objects_path" : "dealer",
"globals_path" : "",
"test_workers": true,
"selenium" : {
  "start_process" : true,
  "server_path" : "lib/drivers/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar",
  "log_path" : "",
  "port" : xxxx,
  "cli_args" : {
    "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "lib/drivers/chromedriver.exe",
    "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "",
    "webdriver.edge.driver" : ""
  }
},

"test_settings" : {
  "chrome" : {
    "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
    "selenium_port"  : xxxx,
    "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
    "silent": true,
    "screenshots" : {
      "enabled" : false,
      "path" : "screenshots/Chrome/"
    },
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "chromeOptions":{
            "args": [
              "disable-web-security",
              "ignore-certificate-errors",
              "--test-type",
              "disable-gpu",
              "start-fullscreen"
            ]
        }          
    }
  },

  "edge" : {
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge"
    }
  }
}
```

}

This is my nightwatch.json config file I don't know what else would be needed, but this is how it looks in my newer config as well.

This is the test I am trying to run

```
    let utils = require('../../consumer/utils');
    let instUrls = require('../../consumer/institutionUrls');
    let fillOutApp = require('../../consumer/fillOutApp');
    let assertions = require('../../consumer/assertions');

    module.exports = {
        '@tags': ['Beta_Consumer_Lendmark'],
        before: function (browser) {
            instUrls(browser).bLendmarkUrl();
        },
        'Start New Application': function (browser) {
            utils(browser).startNewApplication();
        },
        'Fill out Individual Dealer Application': function (browser) {
            fillOutApp(browser).fillOutIndividualDealerApp(30253, 15, 
    'McDonough', 500);
        }, 
        'Save and Reopen': function (browser) {


utils(browser).saveAndReopen('https://sampleurl.com');
        },
         'Assert all Fields are Correct': function (browser) {
            assertions(browser).assertAllFieldsCorrect();
        },
        'Submit the Application': function (browser) {
            utils(browser).submitApplication();
        },
         after: function (browser) {
            browser.end();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I followed this https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Migrating-to-Nightwatch-1.0 and I still get the same errors and am not able to migrate to Nightwatch@1.0.19

Comment: this is specific to what you are trying to do so it's essential to attach the code to your question

Comment: I've attached the nightwatch.json file. What more would be needed?

Comment: The executed test ideally.

Comment: @StratosIon I have provided the necessary code to make it work. Do you know how I can migrate from an older version of nightwatch? The documentation doesn't provide examples or great explanation of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning. This occurs because version 1.0 Nightwatch does not support legacy page objects written prior to version 0.7.
This means that you have to rewrite the code of your page objects based on the following definitions http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#working-with-page-objects

Comment: I get this error when I upgrade and make necessary changes.  Cannot read property 'reduce' of null. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: do you have a correct example of how this can be done?